# Is it bad practice to call formatting functions in the react render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function like:

```
const getTermsUrl = (list) => {
  const allianzInsurances = (list || []).filter(isAllianz)
  return get(first(allianzInsurances), 'productUrl', '')
}
```

also have a component with a render method like:

```
  ...
  render() {
    const { browser, list, selected, loading, invalidFields } = this.props

    // it`s bad practice to formating it in the render? 
    const termsAndConditionsProps = {
      browser,
      invalidFields,
      termsUrl: getTermsUrl(list), 
    }

    return (<TermsAndConditions {...termsAndConditionsProps} />)
  }
  ...
```

My question is: is it bad practice to format `termsAndConditionsProps` during render? Or is it better to keep the formatted version in the local state and format within the constructor?

Comment: It might affect performance a little if there are a lot of re-renders and the computation is heavy. You can memoize the function though so that it doesn't recompute the same thing again and again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok to have lightweight formatting functions and call them inside of component's render method. It makes sense to move such computations in constructor if your prop's don't change. But in the case above your component already gets re-rendered every time when the `list` property gets updated. So in this case it's ok.